# React Hook useEffect missing dependency fix

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Good day. I want to run effect where I'm using `isSplitted` variable in if statement, but only when `playerCounter` changes. I found some solutions for functions used in useEffect (useCallback), but I couldnt find a way to get rid of missing dependency warning for only variable as `isSplitted`. Is there a way to fix it other than disabling linter for this case? Also for the info, I'm using those variables in other fragments of code.

```
const [playerCounter, setPlayerCounter] = useState(0);
const [isSplitted, setIsSplitted] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
        if(playerCounter > 21) {
            if(isSplitted) {      // missing dependency
                setCurrentPlayerHand(HANDS.SECOND);
                return
            }
            setToggleFade(false);
            setShowResult(true);
            setIsDisabled(true);
            setMessage(MESSAGES.LOSE);
            setIsStarted(false);
        }
    }, [playerCounter]);
```

Comment: Why not just add the dependency? Your effect has no side effects, so running it again wont cause an issue. The perf cost is so tiny its actually preferable over any advanced comparitor which is just a source of bugs.

Comment: `isSplitted` may change and it will run the effect, which is not desired

Comment: But actually it is desired here. This is a very common misconception about effects. when it runs again with isSplitted true, the net effect of the state items should be nothing. You also dont need to worry about perf of it running -- its minor and also guarantees consistency. If it isn't a net 0 effect when it runs again it actually means you have a separate state management problem. I can see from your code so far, it is highly likely that some of these state items shouldnt be state, but memoized values -- but would need more context.

Comment: When it flips back to false, the effect needs to ensure it resets anything back to what i needs to be. This is the correct way to conceptually think about it. Avoiding putting it in the deps rather than handling all the edge cases in the effect is a common reason for bugs.

Comment: I'll add its also why that lint rule exists! It is encouraging you to always run the effect every time, and synchronise other state in every edge case.

Comment: yeah, don't lie to deps unless its a `ref` .... you should change your code in effect itself when you are not able to decide what to put in deps .... beta docs have good points on the same, highly recommended to go through ..

Comment: Yes this page is very good (thanks @KcH): https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/removing-effect-dependencies. In this case, he wont be able to "prove isSplitted is not reactive" because he does indeed need to synchronise it.

Comment: yeah agree mate 

Comment: I think also, its highly probable that the effect shouldn't exist and all those state setters should be happening in the event handler for whatever causes player count to go up https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/removing-effect-dependencies#should-this-code-move-to-an-event-handler

Comment: Great catch, that should be it, seeing the variable names declared

Comment: Thank you for this discussion. I'll try to rewrite it. In current approach (whole app) i have multiple useEffect which depends on changing `playerCounter`. Maybe i'll put all of them inside onclick Event

Comment: Yeh, I'd also at the same time consider if any of the state items are actually derived from the other bits of state. If they are, those should be `useMemo`. BTW the mistake is so common you see thes ort of thing like what you did everywhere out there in the wild, even from very experienced react devs. unfortunately `useEffect` is misused often and not well understood. But the beta docs address it.